# .height() function showing wrong value when set to auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have run into this problem when I am using `jquery.load` on a div (whose height is 0px and overflow:hidden) to load in content to that div then do a quick `jquery.css` to change it's height to auto and then use the `.height()` function to get the value of it's `auto` height so when I animate it, I know what value to animate to. The problem is `.height()` is returning 0  as a value the first time I run the function, but the second time it returns the correct value. here is the code that I am working with.

```
$('#adobe').click(function()
{
    $('#info').animate(
    {
        height:'0px'
    },600,function()
    {
        $('#info').load('projects/adobe.html',animateHeight());
    });
});

function animateHeight()
{
    console.log($('#info'));
    var temp = $('#info');
    var curHeight = temp.height();
    temp.css('height', 'auto');
    var autoHeight = temp.height();
    temp.css('height',curHeight);
    console.log(autoHeight);
    $('#info').animate(
    {
        height:autoHeight
    },600);

    $(window).scrollTo($('#info'),600,{axis:'y'});
}
```

Comment: It has to do with the browser redraw mechanism, if you sent the height to `auto` and try to fetch the height, between those two the browser may not have redrawn the ui to recalculate the new height of the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM would not have had time to update itself by the time your `animateHeight()` is called; you could add this to your click handler:

```
$('#info').load('projects/adobe.html', function() { 
    setTimeout(animateHeight, 0); 
});
```

This gives the execution back to the browser to let the DOM update its dimensions before relying on it, especially when they're set to `auto;`.